# What is the best method to store/populate images for Android App?

Tags: android

I am fairly new to Android and I have run into my first problem that I can't seem to find a straight answer to. Here is my problem:

My app is going to be using a list of items, with images for each list row, and when clicked on, the same image and more info on the item will be displayed in a new activity. However, there could be anywhere from 100-500(or more) images that will need to be shown. I have only tested my app w/ about 6 items so far, so memory isn't an issue at the current time, but as I was discussing my app w/ a friend, he made the suggestion of putting the images on a image hosting site and using URLs to reference them.

My question is: Would the URL reference method be the best solution for a high number of images, or would it be better to do it a different way?

If this has been answered and I just overlooked it while searching, I apologize and ask that you point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using 2 things.  The first is an **LruCache** to store each bitmap (See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).  This will take care of managing whether you need to reload a bitmap from disk or not for you.
The second thing you should do is have a **ListView** with a custom Adapter to serve up your views so it can recycle them (Rather than just having a **LinearLayout** within a **ScrollView** or something).  An adapter works by taking an existing view and just setting the content for a particular index.  So for example, if you have an array of items and each item has an image and text to display, you would create an **Adapter** that has the list of items and set it on a **ListView**.  The ListView keeps track of what items are displayed and calls *getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)* for each one.  If a view already exists for that type of item at that position, then the passed in *convertView* will be a view that is currently not being used.  In this case, just set the image and text on it.
If it's null, then it means all the available views are in use so you need to inflate a new one.  In this case inflate it, then set the image/text on it.

For example, your Adapter might look like this:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public class MyListItem {
        String ImagePath;
        String Text;
    }

    ArrayList<MyListItem> mItems;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context mContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyListItem> items) {
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyListItem getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // If you have more than 1 type of view, give each an ID
        //    and return the ID for the view you want to display
        //    at this position in the array list.
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.SOME_VIEW_ID, null);

            // Perhaps set some layout parameters on convertView.
        }

        // Get the item at this position
        MyListItem item = getItem(position);

        // Set properties on the convertView here
        //    For the sake of example, pretend we have a View class
        //    called "ExampleView" with setImagePath and setText methods.
        //    setImagePath could lookup the path in an LruCache and load it
        //    it from disk if it isn't in there.
        ExampleView someCustomView = (ExampleView)convertView;
        someCustomView.setImagePath(item.ImagePath);
        someCustomView.setText(item.Text);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have the custom adapter setup for the list, but i think i need to alter it a bit. But i was just wondering if storing almost 500 images in the app's drawable folder would be wise. I haven't ever put an app on the market, and I don't know what the max size for an app is, nor do I want to take up a lot of memory on someone's device.

But I will use your code example as a reference for when i go to tweak my adapter.

Comment: 500 images in the drawable folder should be fine from Android's point of view.  If you want folders to organize, what I did on another project when I had a bunch of files is have the build system zip it into "res/raw/resources.zip" and then extracted it into external storage on first run.  It also maintained a hash so it could check every build if it needed to re-extract or not.  The maximum size on the Play Store for an APK is 50MB.  They have a mechanism for downloading up to 2GB of additional data after installation, though (See http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking it would be too much for it. 

I will look into the zip method and see how that goes. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think "URL reference" is a good idea.Don’t worry in a lot of images.It won't use too many memory because ListView(Or RecyclerView) cache different views.In the List,you can show some smaller iamges(e.g 100x100),but in another activity you can show the real size image.It's not the same image,there are two images.

You can look these library:

[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: I thought about using UIL, but was trying to find a way to do it without it. I did download the code package as a back up.

Comment: I see.Almost all libraries solve the problem with the URL reference.You can check their code and find a new way.I think the URL reference method  in common use.I'll give the problem attention.